# Can "literature" be used with plural verb?

Tags: grammar

> In general, available literature regarding measurement of boxers’ brain tissue performance using EEG, CT scan, and neuropsychological aspects **is/are** not much consistent and factors such as sample size, technical limitations and sport experience affect inhomogeneity of results.

Oxford Dictionary says that *literature* is uncountable. So, my question is, "Should literature be used with a plural verb or a singular verb, as in the above example, when the author means more than one piece of literature?

Comment: "...are not much consistent" is not a natural way of expression. Using 'very' or nothing before 'consistent' is natural. *literature is not consistent*.

Answer (score 3):

No, *literature* should be used with a singular verb. Uncountable nouns are almost always singular, even if they refer to multiple "items". This is similar to money, where even if you have multiple banknotes, you would say "The money **is** in my pocket."

If you're having trouble understanding why this is so, think of *the literature* not as each individual book or paper, but rather the combined whole.

Comment: But, actually I mean in the question's example that multiple instances of literature are not consistent (confirming one another). Is the verb still singular?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter at all what papers or books are referred to by *literature*, it will still be singular. The literature is not consistent (with itself).